# My global var is losing its value from one function to another

Tags: swift, var

I have an application that when pressing a button should set a custom var that is then used to configure a prepare for segue function. Basically in the prepare for function I am setting up a switch statement to execute the appropriate code.

However if I set the var that will be used by the switch in the IBAction function for the button the var loses its value before the switch command is executed and all I get is the default value of "fail".

I've been looking all over and I know I'm doing something really stupid but I'm a noob and need some help if there's any out there!

```
import UIKit

var mainAppointment = Appt()

class SubMenuOneViewController: UIViewController {
    // func whatsTheService() -> ServiceType {
    //     let serviceSelected = ServiceType.appointment
    //      return serviceSelected
    //  }

    @IBAction func selectAppointmentSetting(_ sender: myFirstButton) {
        //let whatsSelected = serviceTypeSelected.airport

        mainAppointment.serviceType = .petvisit
        mainAppointment.petName = "Beans"
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "appointmentSettingSegue", sender: self)
    }

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        let nav = segue.destination as! UINavigationController
        let apptOrderVC = nav.topViewController as! AppointmentScreenTableViewController

        //switch (serviceTypeSelected).self {
        switch mainAppointment.petName {
        case "Beans":
            apptOrderVC.appointmentTypeString = "Beans"
        default:
            apptOrderVC.appointmentTypeString = "fail"
        }
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean by “the var loses it's value”? What’s the value that you get instead? Also, can you post what `Appt` class/struct is?

Comment: What do you mean by "loses its value"? The way `mainAppointment` is initialized makes in a non-optional, so it can't be `nil`

Comment: I would put some breakpoints to verify the intended flow. One to make sure that the `petName` is set in `selectAppointmentSetting` (btw the signature is wrong - it should something like `sender: <type_of_sender>` instead) and another to check that the value is correct in `prepare(for:)`. Finally, do you _really_ need a global variable for this?...

Comment: When I say lose value it is "". Using debugger the value gets set correctly on the button click but when the segue starts the value for Petname is then back to "". 

As far as a global var being needed, probably not but I'm experimenting with different workflows at the moment and this is the one I'm trying for now..

Basically I want a few buttons that when selected will collect some data and then send through from the button click action to the Prepare for Segue. Somehow the transition from button click to segue execution the data is going away.

Comment: I should mention when I run the app the value "fail" is the one that gets sent forward so the switch is being used but thinks Petname is blank. And thanks for the prompt feedback, you guys are amazing!

Answer (score 0):

well I tried a different approach using the segue identifier within the prepare for segue function and it works perfectly. Probably a better way to go! Thanks for all the feedback!

```
   if segue.identifier == "appointmentSettingSegue" {
            apptOrderVC.appointmentTypeString = "Beans"
        } else {
            apptOrderVC.appointmentTypeString = "fail"
```